# Expectation Propagation and multivariate priors

Tags: machine-learning, probability, inference, approximation

I have been struggling with this for weeks now. All EP examples that I have found on the net seem to deal with univariate priors and I am really at a loss as to how to make it work with a multivariate prior. The scenario is as follows: I am trying to estimate a bunch of parameters where the prior over these parameters form a multivariate Gaussian with off diagonal covariance terms. The likelihood can be written down as a product over individual likelihood for each of these parameters. So, the equation is as follows:

$$
P(w|y) = \frac{1}{Z}P(w)\prod_iP(y_i|w_i)
$$

where $y$ is the observed data and $w$ are the parameters I am trying to estimate. So, when I want to perform inference on this using EP, what should be done with $P(w)$. $P(w)$ is a multivariate Gaussian with 0 mean and a dense covariance matrix. So, at some point I will have to multiply terms between $P(w)$ and $P(y_i|w_i)$ or some similar approximates of it (but the forms are very different). So effectively to compute the functional form of the posterior, I am multiplying a multivariate Gaussian ($P(w)$) with a univariate Gaussian function ($\prod_i{q(y_i|w_i)}$) where $q(y_i|w_i)$ are the approximating factors. How can this be achieved? Does $P(w)$ need to be broken down as well? I am not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to change $w$ to $W$ to differentiate it from the observed variables. Based off the information in the linked question from the comments you have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(W|x, y,\phi) &\propto& P(W,x,y,\phi)\\
&\propto& P(W,y | x, \phi)\\
&=& P(y| W,x,\phi)P(W | x, \phi)\\
&=& P(y | W,x,\phi)P(W)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

So up to normalization the information you seek is
$$P(W|x,y,\phi) \propto \left[\prod_{n=1}^N\frac{\phi}{2\pi}e^{-.5(y_n-t(x_n,W_n))\phi(y_n-t(x_n,W_n))}\right] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma|}}e^{-.5(W-m)^T\Sigma^{-1}(W-m)}$$

The normalized result is
$$P(W|x,y,\phi) = \left[\prod_{n=1}^N\frac{\phi}{2\pi}e^{-.5(y_n-t(x_n,W_n))\phi(y_n-t(x_n,W_n))}\right] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^N|\Sigma|}}e^{-.5(W-m)^T\Sigma^{-1}(W-m)}P(x)P(\phi)$$
If you would like I could comment about why you don't need to use EP in this problem.

Comment: The reason I am confused (and this could be something simple that I do not grasp) is that as I understand in EP, we approximate the posterior distribution by iteratively refining our approximation for each factor. So we will have this local messages where at some point we will need to multiply these messages (AFAI can tell) and this has a factor with a multivariate normal prior and some univariate likelihood terms coming in and I am not sure how these things combine. A detailed question: [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82612/help-with-expectation-propagation-updating-factors)

Comment: With respect to the linked question, are the parameters $m$ and $\Sigma$ in $P(w)$ known?

Comment: This is the parameters of the prior distribution. So, the prior is a 0 mean MVN ($m$=0) with a known covariance structure $\Sigma$.

Comment: Ok - that is what I thought.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, please comment on why EP is not needed :-) Is there some closed form solution?

Comment: I can see that we can get a MAP like point estimate by minimising the equivalent energy function wrt to the parameters to estimate but I am not sure how we can characterise the full posterior?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want to find.  The above formula for $P(W|x,y,\phi)$ is a closed form for the p.d.f. of the posterior probability.

Comment: Oh yes but I need to for example, find the mean and the variance of such a distribution. Also this is a scaled PDF, so unless one computes the integral of this expression as well for the denominator in the Bayes theorem, it is not the PDF. otherwise, usually then one is left to resort to doing some sampling to characterise this high dimensional posterior (which can get computationally expensive) distribution.

Comment: Yes, EP is meant to estimate the mean and variance of the prior.  We know the closed form of the pdf so we will get more accurate and more quantifiable estimates via numerical integration.

Comment: Anyway, the reason I don't think you need EP is because EP is a generalization of BP.  In BP, the goal is to eliminate any nodes in your Bayesian Network that are either not observed or not accounted for in the prior you seek.  You have no such nodes.

Comment: You say mea and variance of the prior. You mean the posterior? The prior is set and does not change. Anyway, I will read a bit more about this as well. I think I need to look at how these messages are created and perhaps that will give some insight.

Comment: Sorry, indeed I meant posterior.